# number of closed-loop graphs in square lattice

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, puzzle, algebraic-graph-theory, planar-graphs

Suppose I have a $N\times N$ square lattice. I want to know how many different closed-loop diagrams are there. The closed-loop diagrams can have no loop, one loop, two loops, etc. If two loops share the same boundary, then the boundary disappears and these two loops merge into one big loop. Next, I want to know how many different closed-loop diagrams are there going through a particular link. If the ratio of number of different closed-loop diagrams through a particular link to the number of different closed-loop diagrams a fixed number? Furthermore, how many different closed-loop diagrams are there going through two particular links and is the ratio to the total number of different diagrams a fixed number?

Comment: What have you done?  Do you know the answers for small $N$?

Comment: Note that in order to have a closed loop, you have to make as much steps left as right and as much steps down as up.

Comment: Does a figure $8$ count?  That is, two squares that share one vertex.

Comment: @saulspatz Figure 8 counts as two loops. For small N, if it is 1x1, you have two diagrams. If it is 2x2, you have 1+4+4+4+1+2=16 (if I count it correctly).

Comment: @saulspatz Reasonable guess. But not sure if it is correct. And moreover, I want to know the ratio of closed-graph diagrams through a particular link to all closed-graph diagrams.

Comment: I had second thoughts, and deleted the comment, but now I think it's probably right.  Working on a proof.  I have no idea about the second part yet.

Comment: A link is an edge of one of the small squares, right?

Comment: @saulspatz A link is just the edge connecting pair of nearest neighbor vertexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of closed loop diagrams is equal to the number of subsets of the set of small squares.  It is clear that any such subset results in a closed-loop diagram by cancelling common edges.  On the other hand given a closed-loop diagram, for each loop, mark all the small squares that lie within that loop.  A square lying inside more than one loop is marked multiple times.  The set of squares that have been marked an odd number of times generates the loop diagram.  Therefore, there are $2^{N^2}$ closed-loop diagrams.

If a link lies on the edge of the large square it will, will be in a closed loop diagram once for every subset of the other squares, so in $2^{N^2-1}$ closed-loop diagrams, that is, half the total.

All other edges lie on two squares.  They lie on the diagram is one or the other or both squares are in the subset, along with any subset of the other squares.  This is $2\cdot2^{N^2-2}$, so half the total once again.

Comment: It is a great idea! For the total number, it actually can be obtained using binomial theorem (x+y)^(N^2) by choosing x=y=1.

Comment: Using the smallest squares to count is really a great idea! I managed to get the number of closed-loop diagrams going through two particular links to be 2^(N^2-2).